# javascript Uncaught TypeError while drawing on HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawing

I am trying to draw a series of images on an HTML5 Canvas .
For eg - For the word APPLE , I am trying to put 5 pictures - A.png, B.png, C.png etc in series to display the word . My code is as below:

```
var x = 100; 
var word = "APPLE";
var imageArray = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
  imageArray[i] = new Image();
  imageArray[i].onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(imageArray[i], x, 25, 70, 70); // canvas context
    x += 80;
  };
  imageArray[i].src = "images/"+word.charAt(i)+".png";
}
```

I get an Error -

javascript Uncaught TypeError: Type error

Can someone please explain me why is occuring and what is the best way to achieve this ?

Comment: Did you try drawing `this` instead? You're suffering from JavaScript not having block scoping.

Comment: Could it be that charAt returns nothing when the parameter is larger than the length of the string, so when you try to draw the higher 'i' values its using a 404 as the image and not a valid image file? (because apple only has 5 characters and your loop goes to ten)

Comment: Corrected the question . I had put i<10 in my stackoverflow question just for simplicity . Corrected it now .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several possible error sources in you code:

1. if you want to iterate over every letter in your word, you should stop at the end of the word and not at index 10:

   ```
   var word = "APPLE"; // has 5 letters
   for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
     // ... do your code
   }
   ```
2. Within the callback `onload = function() ...` you access the `imageArray[i]` which is not what you intend to, as the value of `i` modifies and at the time it is called, you access the first element *behind* your desired array. Additionally, you can not rely on each letter being loaded in the correct sequence. You can avoid both of these error, by using `forEach`:

   ```
   var word = "APPLE"; // again, the 5 letter word
   // transform the word to an array ['A', 'P', 'P', 'L', 'E']
   var letters = word.split('');
   letters.forEach(function(letter, index) {
     var image = new Image();
     image.onload = function() {
       context.drawImage(image, x + index * 80, 25, 70, 80);
     }
     image.src = "images/" + letter + ".png";
   })
   ```

Comment: Sorry .Corrected the question . I had put i<10 in my stackoverflow question just for simplicity . Corrected it now .

Answer (score 2):

After your loop exits, `imageArray` and `i` are kept inside the onload functions you created.  `i` incremented again after your last iteration so it is now pointing to an undefined element in your array.  You can use a function to create a new scope:

```
for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
  imageArray[i] = new Image();
  imageArray[i].onload = (function(i){
    return function() {
      // i in here is now the outer function parameter instead
      // of the i in the function that creates the images
      context.drawImage(this, x+i*80, 25, 70, 70);
    }
  })(i);
  imageArray[i].src = "images/"+word.charAt(i)+".png";
}
```

Tharabas answer is generally nicer, however `forEach` won't work in IE < 9

Comment: If I use this , the letters are not in synch . For Apple , it messages up the Arrangement .

Comment: Fixed.  I still had a closure problem with `x` that I had originally fixed with `i`.